# iphone os 4.0 and libxml2 and os 2.2.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xml-libxml

My project using `libxml2` and i want to compile my application with `iOS 4.0` with **deployment target 2.2.1**

but I am getting errors for `libxml2` what is the way to do this.

```
I want compile on iOS 4.0 and deployment target to 2.2.1 with libxml2 support.
```

Looking for answers. thanks in Advance

Comment: The iPhone OS 4.0 betas are still under NDA, so answering this question would be a violation of one's developer agreement.

Comment: 4.0 stuff belongs in the Apple forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try your luck :

After adding the libxml2 just include "$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2" in your Header search path....

It's the way ,you can use this framework..

Note: Clean all target and build the app again.

Hope it works for you like me